# How to start a WebSphere MQ in SHARED mode?

Tags: ibm-mq

We encounted an error wherein the Oracle support said we need to restart the IBM Websphere MQ in SHARED mode, but I cannot find a documentation on how to do it. I consulted some MQ teams and they are also puzzled with the requested option. Can I have some link on how to do it? The Oracle KnowledgeBase article follows:

> Symptoms
>   You have successfully configured the MQ adapter, but upon use you receive an com.ibm.mq.MQException error in the logs
>
> Cause
>   The IBM MQ error is suggesting that the MQ has been started in exclusive mode, and that an earlier process already has a lock on the MQ
>
> Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
>   MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
>   Closure reason = 2009
>
> This is an IBM error indicating an EXCLUSIVE mode MQ
>   Solution
>   Start the MQ in SHARED mode, or verify that no other process has already connected to the MQ when started in Exclusive mode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think they are referring to how the adapter opens a MQ queue. A queue can be opened in a shared or exclusive mode. In shared mode more than one application can consume messages from a queue. In exclusive mode only one application can open a queue and consume messages.  Check `SHARE` and `DEFSOPT` settings (via MQSC) for the queue being used by Oracle adapter.